# Breaker trips when both switches on circuit are on

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan

I've got a ceiling fan/light wired to a double switch (like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Combination-Double-Switch-White-R62-05224-2WS/202027008)

The source is at the switch and it's wired like this image:

[image]

I can turn either switch on, but when I turn both on, the breaker trips.

In trouble shooting, I tried this on the same line, but the same thing happened (each switch worked individually, but when both were on the breaker tripped): 
[image]

Comment: Is the tripped breaker a GFCI/breaker combo?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you've done diagnostically so far? The most obvious explanations are: the breaker is defective; or, the fan and light together, along with whatever else is on that circuit, draw more than the rating of the breaker. Are you sure neither of these things are true? If so, why?

Comment: @PeterDuniho it's a 15 amp breaker with 2 LED lamps (like this:  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Euri-Lighting-11-5-Watt-White-Integrated-LED-Ceiling-Flush-Mount-EIN-CL06WH-203/306043692 ) . Diagnostically - there are other outlets on the same breaker that work normally (until the breaker is tripped). I think the problem has to be with how I am connecting the neutral...

Comment: @GlennWillen no

Comment: _"I think the problem has to be with how I am connecting the neutral"_ -- maybe. I don't have any specific ideas. But, for the benefit of the others who might be able to help you, I'll suggest that providing actual photos of the wiring at each end will be of more direct use than the schematic drawing. The schematic conveys your understanding of the circuit, while photos will ensure it's clear the _actual_ state of the circuit (or at least, as clear as a photo can make it).

Comment: Aside from the normal switch, does the breaker have a TEST button? Any LEDs on the breaker itself?  Any indications from same?

Comment: @PeterDuniho will do, thank you for the help!

Comment: Test voltage at source: 230V across live and neutral, 230V across live and PE, around 0V across neutral and PE. Also test voltages at light fixture in all the switch possible position. Also please post a picture of the actual wall box and of the ceiling box.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like either there's too much load already on the circuit and the combination of light and fan pushed it over the edge, or you have an electrical problem in that switch, the fan/light fixture, or in how they're connected to power and each other.

I'd start by turning off everything else on that circuit and seeing if that lets you turn both these switches on; if that works, it's excessive load and you need to reduce the demand. Switching to LED light bulbs might be enough; if not see if there is something you can easily move to another circuit.

If that doesn't do it, you're back to inspecting wiring by eye and with a a meter to find the point of failure.